# Boost vectors versus STL vectors

Tags: c++, boost, stl, vector, ublas

How do `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` and `std::vector` compare in runtime efficiency?

Is it safe to assume that I can convert an entire program from using `std::vector` to use `boost::numeric::ublas::vector` just by writing:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
```

instead of `#include<vector>`? Can I just use boost vectors as if they were STL vectors in all aspects?

Do functions from `<algorithm>` work with boost vectors? Do they use the same iterators?

Do they work in C++0x? Do they work for range based loops?

Comment: what's wrong with `std::vector`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should only use ublas::vector if you want to do linear algebra operations, such as matrix vector multiplication etc.
They do not provide the same functionality nor the same interface as std::vector.
In terms of run-time efficiency, there is nothing, that I know of, that beats std::vector.

Comment: Really?  Cause I'm pretty sure linked lists like std::list beat vector for insertion and removal of elements. :p

Comment: @wheaties I also thought so, but was shocked to see that vector is mostly good even for that.

Comment: it really depends on the size. Insertion in the middle of a huge `std::vector` should be way slower than insertion in the middle of an equally huge `std::list`.

Comment: see [here for evidence/benchmark](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/054.htm) of what BlaXpirit is saying. Granted, size is the important element here.

Comment: @rubenvb : To be fair, that was benchmarked with MSVC 5, which was released in _Feb 1997_ -- not exactly current. ;-]

Comment: For inserting at the end of the container, one item at a time, on my Ubuntu laptop there is no size in which `list<int>` outperforms `vector<int>`.  For inserting at the beginning of the container, `list<int>` measurably outperforms `vector<int>` for even modest (approximately 5000) size.

Answer (score 24):

These are completely orthogonal data types: the former represents the algebraic definition of 'vector' (a one-dimensional matrix), while the latter represents the computer science definition of 'vector' (a one-dimensional array).

They *don't* compare.

Comment: Gods! I searched the whole world thinking why isn't there a `push_back` in boost vector.. :)

Comment: note: stl algorithms still work. and you can use arithmetics by wrapping functions like `plus_assign` into a lambda    http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/numeric/ublas/functional.hpp